# lost current local language after login and after logout

Tags: php, symfony, routes, fosuserbundle

i can switch language of my web site correctly but when i log in, i lost my current language in the url. for exemple before login http://test.bu/app_dev.php/en/admin/slideshow/ and after login i have this http://test.bu/app_dev.php/fr/admin/slideshow/
symfony2.7 takes always locale: fr. i use FosUserBundle. i ggogled i find that i can use bundles to fix this but i think i can resolve this by editing confinguration.
after login i redirect the web site by the default_target_path:    slideshow_index like this

```
app_slideshow:
    resource: "@AppBundle/Resources/config/routing/slideshow.yml"
    prefix:   /{_locale}/admin/slideshow
```

---

```
this is my config.yml

imports:
    - { resource: parameters.yml }
    - { resource: security.yml }
    - { resource: services.yml }

# Put parameters here that don't need to change on each machine where the app is deployed
# https://symfony.com/doc/current/best_practices/configuration.html#application-related-configuration
parameters:
    locale: fr

framework:
    #esi: ~
    translator: { fallback: %locale% }
    secret: '%secret%'
    router:
        resource: '%kernel.root_dir%/config/routing.yml'
        strict_requirements: ~
    form: ~
    csrf_protection: ~
    validation: { enable_annotations: true }
    #serializer: { enable_annotations: true }
    templating:
        engines: ['twig']
    default_locale: '%locale%'
    trusted_hosts: ~
    trusted_proxies: ~
    session:
        # handler_id set to null will use default session handler from php.ini
        handler_id: ~
    fragments: ~
    http_method_override: true

# Twig Configuration
twig:
    debug: '%kernel.debug%'
    strict_variables: '%kernel.debug%'

# Doctrine Configuration
doctrine:
    dbal:
        driver: pdo_mysql
        host: '%database_host%'
        port: '%database_port%'
        dbname: '%database_name%'
        user: '%database_user%'
        password: '%database_password%'
        charset: UTF8
        # if using pdo_sqlite as your database driver:
        #   1. add the path in parameters.yml
        #     e.g. database_path: '%kernel.root_dir%/data/data.db3'
        #   2. Uncomment database_path in parameters.yml.dist
        #   3. Uncomment next line:
        #path: '%database_path%'

    orm:
        auto_generate_proxy_classes: '%kernel.debug%'
        naming_strategy: doctrine.orm.naming_strategy.underscore
        auto_mapping: true

# Swiftmailer Configuration
swiftmailer:
    transport: '%mailer_transport%'
    host: '%mailer_host%'
    username: '%mailer_user%'
    password: '%mailer_password%'
    spool: { type: memory }
# app/config/config.yml
fos_user:
    db_driver: orm # other valid values are 'mongodb' and 'couchdb'
    firewall_name: main
    user_class: Gold\UserBundle\Entity\User
    from_email:
        address: "%mailer_user%"
        sender_name: "%mailer_user%"

  thanks stackoverflow
```

Comment: I have solved this problem this morning by installing jms routing bundle.

Comment: give me  the link please of  jms routing bundle

Comment: I will write in  2 min  you an entire  answer. with links and config.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Link of JMS routing bundle https://github.com/schmittjoh/JMSI18nRoutingBundle

But before you install it please look at this short video tutorial. This tutorial helped me a lot to understand the problem you are having between fos user bundle and the locale in url.

https://codereviewvideos.com/course/getting-started-with-fosuserbundle/video/translations-and-internationalisation-in-fosuserbundle

If you don't want to install jms routing bundle with your composer.json file you can install it with this command `php composer.phar require jms/i18n-routing-bundle "dev-master"`

Here is my config:

```
jms_i18n_routing:
    default_locale: "%locale%"
    locales: ["fr", "en"]
    strategy: prefix_except_default
```

Security.yml:

```
firewalls:
    main:
        pattern: ^/
        form_login:
            provider: fos_userbundle
            csrf_token_generator: security.csrf.token_manager
            require_previous_session: false
            login_path: fos_user_security_login
            check_path: fos_user_security_check
            default_target_path: your_route_name_homepage
        logout:
            path: fos_user_security_logout
            target: your_route_name_homepage        
        anonymous: true


        access_control:
             - { path: ^/login$, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY && !IS_AUTHENTICADED_FULLY  }
             - { path: ^/register, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY && !IS_AUTHENTICADED_FULLY }
             - { path: ^/resetting, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
             - { path: ^/admin/, role: ROLE_ADMIN }
```

After having installed Jms routing bundle. Try to execute the commande `debug/router` (symfony 3) and watch the routes names and prefix.

Comment: in my   my access_control i shood add /en/ and /fr/ else i can access to admin without authentification 
        - { path: ^/en/admin/, role: ROLE_ADMIN }
        - { path: ^/fr/admin/, role: ROLE_ADMIN }
@Mintho433 you think my solution is logical !? thank you

Comment: I updated my answer to show you what I have in my access control key.

Answer (score 1):

You can handle the locale detection/switch with [JMSI18nRoutingBundle](https://github.com/schmittjoh/JMSI18nRoutingBundle)

Add the required bundles to composer.json:

```
"require": {
    ...
    "jms/i18n-routing-bundle": "1.1.*",
    "jms/translation-bundle": "1.1.*",
    "friendsofsymfony/user-bundle": "1.3.*"
},
```

http://jmsyst.com/bundles/JMSI18nRoutingBundle/master/installation